# Translating Accelerometer Vectors from Device to Earth Coordinates

Tags: android, rotation, accelerometer, coordinate-transformation, rotational-matrices

I have scoured the internet and StackOverflow to find a way to translate Android accelerometer vectors from the device coordinate system to Earth coordinate systems.  I am using the Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR to do this.  I am accessing the sensors using NativeScript and using MathJS to do matrix computations.

1. I grab the rotation vector using Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR
2. I calculate the rotation matrix following the Android code for getRotationMatrixFromVector() given at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java.
   ---2.1 I calculate q0, q1=acceleration.x, q2=acceleration.y, q3=acceleration.z
   ---2.2 I tried calculating the rotation matrix using both the float[9] and float[16] matrix sizes but I can't get either of them to work.
   ---2.3 I tried inverting and transposing both these rotation matrices.
3. I now multiply the rotation matrix (tried normal, inverted, and  transpose) by the matrix [[accel.x],[accel.y],[accel.z],[0.0]] (4x1 matrix)
4. When I look at my newly translated acceleration values, they aren't rotated at all.  If I point my device's x-axis toward the Earth's north and accelerate it this direction, my acceleration.x will be >1 and the other values almost 0.  Here my acceleration.y should be translated to be >1.  Similarly, if I point my device's y-axis toward the sky and accelerate it this direction, my acceleration.y reads >1 when my acceleration.z should read >1.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in these steps?  The consensus seems to be grab the rotation vector, transform it to a rotation matrix, invert the matrix, then multiply this inverted matrix by the accelerometer vector.  It doesn't work for me.  Thanks,

```
    var r;
    var rinv;
    accelerometer.startAccelerometerUpdates(function (accel) {
        if (accel.sensortype == 11) {
            var q0 = Math.sqrt(1 - accel.x*accel.x - accel.y*accel.y - accel.z*accel.z);
            var q1 = accel.x;
            var q2 = accel.y;
            var q3 = accel.z;
            //calculate rotation matrix from unit quaternion
            var sq1 = 2*q1*q1;
            var sq2 = 2*q2*q2;
            var sq3 = 2*q3*q3;
            var q1q2 = 2*q1*q2;
            var q3q0 = 2*q3*q0;
            var q1q3 = 2*q1*q3;
            var q2q0 = 2*q2*q0;
            var q2q3 = 2*q2*q3;
            var q1q0 = 2*q1*q0;
            //r = math.matrix([[1-sq2-sq3,q1q2-q3q0,q1q3+q2q0],[q1q2+q3q0,1-sq1-sq3,q2q3-q1q0],[q1q3-q2q0,q2q3+q1q0,1-sq1-sq2]]);
            r = math.matrix([[1-sq2-sq3,q1q2-q3q0,q1q3+q2q0,0.0],[q1q2+q3q0,1-sq1-sq3,q2q3-q1q0,0.0],[q1q3-q2q0,q2q3+q1q0,1-sq1-sq2,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]]);
            rinv = math.inv(r);
        }
        if (accel.sensortype == 10) {
            //filter accelerometer errors
            if (Math.abs(accel.x) < 10 || Math.abs(accel.y) < 10 || Math.abs(accel.z) < 10) {
                if ((Math.abs(accel.x) > .15 && Math.abs(accel.x)/oldAX < 2) || (Math.abs(accel.y) > .15 && Math.abs(accel.y)/oldAY < 2) || (Math.abs(accel.z) > .15 && Math.abs(accel.z)/oldAZ < 2)) {  //filter errors in accelerometer
                    var Ad = math.matrix([[accel.x],[accel.y],[accel.z],[0.0]]);
                    //transform acceleration values from device coordinates to Earth coordinates
                    var Ag = math.multiply(rinv,Ad);
                    var ax = Ag.get([0,0]);
                    var ay = Ag.get([1,0]);
                    var az = Ag.get([2,0]);
                    if (ax > 1 || ay > 1 || az > 1) {  //only show large values for easier analyses
                        page.getViewById("rotationLabel").text = "Earth Axes Acceleration \n x: " + ax + "\ny: " + ay + "\nz: " + az;
                    }
```

I expect the device's accelerometer values to be translated to the Earth's coordinate system like on this page at the rotation vector portion. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NativeScript-Accelerometer-Advanced plugin is coded incorrectly.  Calculating the unit quaternion value q0 is not necessary as it is provided by the sensor.  Dividing by gravity (9.81 m/s^2) is not necessary as it is not included in the sensors.  I fixed this in my local copy and my rotation method is working correctly:
1. Get rotation vector
2. Calculate rotation matrix
3. Invert rotation matrix
4. Multiply inverted rotation matrix by accelerometer vector with [1.0] appended as the 4th row